# Eclipse Project Explorer that highlights files with compilation errors in Vim?

Tags: eclipse, vim, compiler-errors

What I mean is this:

[image]

If there are errors in any of the source files, Eclipse would in very good fashion highlight files that have problems. This is something I've been missing when I use Vim. So my question is, are there any vim plugins that replicates this behavior? some extension for NerdTree maybe?

Comment: You are using a **Text Editor** instead of an IDE and complaining about it missing a typical IDE feature. Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: Whats makes even more sense is that you of all people, a Vim user as well, and you're trolling me for wanting an eclipse feature when you did the same with VIM + eclim? Additionally, what word or sentence in my question did I convey negative emotions towards VIM? I love VIM! I was merely asking a question if something Eclipse can do, Vim can do too! What gives?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to use Eclim for about a week, years ago, because Vim didn't and still doesn't support Actionscript. As in *no syntax/indent/completion/ftplugin/whatever*: nothing at all. I hoped that Eclim could be a workaround which ended up not being the case: I simply gave up and kept using Flash Builder. I wasn't looking for IDE features, only *basic* support. What *you* are "missing" is typically an IDE feature. Missing IDE features when using a text editor doesn't really makes sense IMO: if I want IDE features I use an IDE. But to each his own, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim has a different mechanism called the `quickfix` list. Basically you run the `:make` command which depending on your buffer runs what ever `'makeprg'` is set to. The results get put into the `quickfix` list. You can then use `:cnext`, `:cprev` to move between the errors. You can use `:cnfile` and `:cpfile` to go to the next and previous file in the list. You can also view the list via `:copen`.

I recommend using Tim Pope's excellent [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin which provides some nice mappings like: `[q` and `]q`,  mappings to move through the `quickfix` list.

For more help see:

```
:h :make
:h 'makeprg'
:h quickfix
:h :cn
:h :cnf
```

Comment: Absolutely right. Because Vim has no built-in project explorer, the quickfix list is the solution. Though plugins like _netrw_ or _NERDTree_ could fetch the quickfix list and display files with errors differently; might be a nice enhancement.